# Google AppEngine adding modules wihout maven

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

i have gone through lot of search result, and couldn't find what i want, i have been using appengine for long time, with single war directory its nice and easy. Now Google Announced Appengine Modules are available for GA, i have read all about it, and i know how it works.

my question is , **how do i add modules to appengine without maven?**,i dont want to use maven, i kind of fustrated with GAE + Maven + Eclipse, no hot redeployment.

so can anyone give me a example for how to add modules to appengine app without maven support.

Another Question is, i know lot of people are using appengine with maven, but i tried a lot to make all three (GAE + maven + eclipse) work, but i couldn't.

**so people using appengine with maven, can you people recommend better way to use it?**

Thanks!

Comment: For moderators, i know my second question appears in many stackoverflow question, but none of those answers are clear enough for many, so dont mark the second question as duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - when you say you want to _add modules to appengine_ do you mean you want to split an existing project into multiple modules?  It's certainly possible without Maven and Google have [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform) to get you started. Essentially you have one 'application' (EAR) project, which references the modules, each of which is its own (WAR) project.

Comment: Okay , so for module support i should use dynamic web project , cant it be done with normal appengine application like one default project type in google appengine?

my question to be clear is, i want to add modules to either new or existing project, say for example new project without the need of maven, because all example are given with maven support

Comment: That's right. You still get the Google App Engine menu items with _dynamic web project_, but they're not quite the same.  Once you have reconfigured your existing app, you can easily add modules.  A module is its own Eclipse project and can easily be added to the `application.xml` descriptor.

Comment: I am wrestling with converting backends to modules as well with my question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941772/serving-multiple-gae-modules-from-one-development-server/23024113?noredirect=1#23024113). It does work fine without Maven but I can't figure out how to make modules share a local_db.bin in a dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Create EAR project by selecting `Java EE > Enterprise Application Project`, and then select `Google App Engine` as `Target runtime`. After that, just add web modules to the EAR project with selecting `Google App Engine` as `Target runtime`

Comment: good info. How to deply the gae project with modules into app engine.

Answer (score 0):

See my detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941772/serving-multiple-gae-modules-from-one-development-server/23499780#23499780) to Aquilon's question. I have included an example.

As to your other question ("cant it be done with normal appengine application like one default project type in google appengine"): Guessing from the documentation, yes, the project type Google Web Application would also support multi-modules, but only as sub-structures within the same project, and no further integration features and support by Eclipse. So this does not make much sense to me, you'd be better off with Maven then.

I prefer to have separate Eclipse projects for the modules, as this is more consistent with the idea of modularization - not only in the server runtime, but also in the code structure. And it is more consistent with the way we manage non-GAE applications in JEE.