# Is maven goal appengine:backends_configure deprecated?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, appengine-maven-plugin

The following command says that there's a goal called "appengine:backends_configure" for the Google App Engine Maven Plugin (https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/)?

I see this goal is available when I run this command:

```
mvn help:describe -Dplugin=appengine
```

Here's what it looks like:

> mosofskcbookpro:myguestbooktrial mosofsky$ mvn help:describe
>   -Dplugin=appengine [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]  [INFO] Using the builder
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder
>   with a thread count of 1 [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building myguestbooktrial 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:describe (default-cli) @
>   myguestbooktrial --- [INFO]
>   com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.14
>
> Name: A Maven Plugin for running and deploying appengine applications
>   Description: The App Engine maven plugin which can be used to interact
>   with   both the development server and the remote runtime. Group Id:
>   com.google.appengine Artifact Id: appengine-maven-plugin Version:
>   1.9.14 Goal Prefix: appengine
>
> This plugin has 29 goals:
>
> appengine:backends_configure   Description: Configure the specified
>   backend.
>   ...

According to Google, though, backends are deprecated (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends).

So is the appengine-maven-plugin just out of date?  When it refers to backends, is that the deprecated backend or some other backend?  Is there a new version of appengine-maven-plugin that can configure modules?

Comment: According to [Maven Central Search Engine](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|appengine-maven-plugin) no newer version available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modules with the appengine-maven-plugin by creating an Enterprise Archive (EAR) project and putting each module in it's own WAR. A contributor's example project which does this is at [1]. Using Maven with modules has some limitations, like not being able to share the same datastore on the development server. In this case you'd want to set up an Eclipse WTP project as per [2].

The documentation on this is somewhat lacking, and it would be nice if Google provided an archetype for using modules.

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java
[2] [Serving multiple GAE modules from one development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941772)

As far as 'appengine:backends_configure' goes, since backends are still supported for now I assume the goal isn't going away any time soon.

Comment: are you certain about not being able to share the same datastore in the development server.  I thought for sure I've been able to get that working with modules implemented with Maven.  I completely agree about the Google documentation lacking.  I've posted many times on StackOverflow about the Google modules documentation.